# Why won't a simple AND gate neural network work without BIAS?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent, perceptron

A simple neural net of 2 inputs and one output without a bias, like this - doesn't seem to work.

```
|input1||weight1 weight2| = Z
|input2|
```

**output = sigmoid(Z)**

Whereas, it works perfectly when BIAS is added, why does it work & what is the math behind it?

```
|input1||weight1 weight2| = Z
|input2|
```

**output = sigmoid(Z - BIAS)**

Here's the CODE to working version with BIAS:

```py
import numpy as np
import random as r
import sys

def sigmoid(ip, derivate=False):
    if derivate:
        return ip*(1-ip)
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-1*ip))

class NeuralNet:
    global sigmoid 

    def __init__(self):
        self.inputLayers = 2
        self.outputLayer = 1
        self.bias = r.random()

    def setup(self):
        self.i = np.array([r.random(), r.random()], dtype=float).reshape(2,)
        self.w = np.array([r.random(), r.random()], dtype=float).reshape(2,)

    def forward_propogate(self):
        self.z = self.w*self.i
        self.o = sigmoid(sum(self.z)-self.bias)

    def optimize_cost(self, desired):
        i=0
        current_cost = pow(desired - self.o, 2)
        for weight in self.w:
            dpdw =  -1*(desired-self.o) * (sigmoid(self.o, derivate=True)) * self.i[i]
            self.w[i] = self.w[i] - 2*dpdw
            i+=1
        #calculate dp/dB
        dpdB = -1*(desired-self.o) * (sigmoid(self.o, derivate=True)) * -1
        self.bias = self.bias - 2*dpdB
        self.forward_propogate()

    def train(self, ip, op):
        self.i = np.array(ip).reshape(2,)
        self.forward_propogate()
        self.optimize_cost(op[0])

n = NeuralNet()
n.setup()
# while sys.stdin.read(1):
success_rate = 0
trial=0
done = False
while not done:
    a = [0.1,1,0.1,1]
    b = [0.1,0.1,1,1]
    c = [0,0,0,1]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        trial +=1
        n.train([a[i],b[i]],[c[i]])
        if c[i] - n.o < 0.01:
            success_rate +=1
            print(100*success_rate/trial, "%")
        if 100*success_rate/trial > 99 and trial > 4:
            print(100*success_rate/trial, "%")
            print("Network trained, took: {} trials".format(trial))
            print("Network weights:{}, bias:{}".format(n.w, n.bias))
            done = True
            break
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work?"

Comment: Weight don't move towards optimal values to get desired output.

Answer (score 1):

A bias is just a shift of the intercept.  The NN you have set up in this example appears to be a single layer neural network with no hidden layers, which is effectively a logistic regression, which is just a linear model.

When you don't learn an intercept value, the intercept defaults to `0`, so it always passes through the origin and you're just learning the slope of the line.  To correctly classify the AND of your data, i.e. the top right corner at `(1,1)`, but not any of the other points, you *need* a non zero intercept because there is no line that passes through the origin that will only have the top right corner on one side and the other three points on the other side.